# Making a Basic Jumper (like Doodle Jump) in Processing 3.5.3, but I can't get the player to move mid-jump?

Tags: java, processing

Below is my code, as I understand it, the player should be both moving and jumping while in the air, because in the draw() function, it is two if statements, not an if-else. I assume keyPressed() checks the keyboard input constantly, since holding a key will make the square move constantly. However after jumping, the character will not move at all if the key is held beginning while the cube is in a jump. Please help!

This code is literally the entire project; I plan on adding platforms in the future, and then I will go from there.

```java
boolean newletter;
boolean direction;
boolean jump;
float velocity;
float velocityconst;
Player player;

class Player {
    color c;
    float xpos;
    float ypos;
    float xspeed;

    Player(color clr, float xPos, float yPos, float xSpeed) {
        c = clr;
        xpos = xPos;
        ypos = yPos;
        xspeed = xSpeed;
    }

    void display() {
        rectMode(CENTER);
        noStroke();
        fill(c);
        rect(xpos,ypos,20,20);
    }

    void drive(boolean dir) {
        if ((xpos + xspeed) > width && (dir)) {
            float remainder = float(width) - xpos;
            xpos = 0 + (xspeed - remainder);
        } else if ((xpos - xspeed) < 0 && !(dir)) {
            float remainder = xpos - 0;
            xpos = width - (xspeed - remainder);
        } else {
            if (dir) xpos += xspeed;
            else xpos -= xspeed;
        }
    }

    void jump() {
        velocity = velocity + 0.5;
        if(ypos + velocity > (height/2)) {
            ypos = height/2;
            jump = false;
            velocity = velocityconst;
        } else {
            ypos += velocity;
        }
    }
}

void setup() {
    size(1000,1000);
    player = new Player(color(255,0,0),0,height/2,10);
    velocityconst = -8.0;
    velocity = velocityconst;
}

void draw() {
    background(255);
    if(newletter == true) {
        player.drive(direction);
    }
    if(jump == true) {
        player.jump();
    }
    player.display();
    newletter = false;
}

void keyPressed()
{
    if((key == 'A') || (key == 'a')) {
        direction = false;
        newletter = true;

    } else if ((key == 'D') || (key == 'd')) {
        direction = true;
        newletter = true;

    } else {
        newletter = false;
    }

    if ((key == 'W') || (key == 'w')) {
        jump = true;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 reasons preventing, that the player is moving and jumping simultaneously.

1. The state which indicates the movement (`newletter`) is reset in every frame:

> ```java
> void draw() {
>
>    // [...]
>
>    newletter = false;
> }
> ```

2. When the key which is pressed is not <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd>, then the movement is stopped:

> ```java
> void keyPressed()
> {
>    if((key == 'A') || (key == 'a')) {
>        // [...]
>    } else if ((key == 'D') || (key == 'd')) {
>        // [...]
>    } else {
>        newletter = false;
>    }
>
>    // [...]
> }
> ```

Don't stop the movement in `draw()`:

```java
void draw() {
    background(255);

    println(newletter, " ", jump);
    if(newletter == true) {
      player.drive(direction);
    }
    if(jump == true) {
        player.jump();
    }

    player.display();
}
```

and don't stop it when <kbd>w</kbd> (or another key) is pressed:

```java
void keyPressed()
{
    if(key == 'A' || key == 'a') {
        direction = false;
        newletter = true; 
    } else if (key == 'D' || key == 'd') {
        direction = true;
        newletter = true;
    }

    if (key == 'W' || key == 'w') {
        jump = true;
    } 
}
```

But add a [`keyReleased()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyReleased_.html) callback, to stop the movement, when <kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>d</kbd> is released:

```java
void keyReleased()
{
    if (key == 'A' || key == 'a' || key == 'D' || key == 'd') {
        newletter = false;
    }
}
```

[image]